# How to get the HTML page after executing java Script

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, ios4

I am using

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"validate(x);"]
```

to execute a java script function and I am getting return value that is returned by "validate(x)"

but i want HTML page (response, ie WEB page) that will be displayed after executing java script function.

Is there any way to do so in objective C programming?

Comment: try using loadHTMLString:baseURL:

Comment: its not working for me as the base string (ie javascript function return) value is nil..

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling

```
NSString *htmlContents = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Some time after

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"validate(x)"];
```

Maybe you could process UIWebView delegate's methods from `UIWebViewDelegate when` it finishes loading the page,

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

but I'm not sure if it will work with your JS.

Comment: You may try [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"] as well, one of these two works (I use them in my projects). If you're not getting response that means you're doing something wrong.

Comment: in this case i will get the response but i want response after executing the javascript function..

Comment: Good, then re-read the part about "some time after". I doubt executing your JS trigger webViewDidFinishLoad, so you may rely on some timer or stuff. Note that js will be executed for no more then 10 sec (if > 10sec, execution will be terminated whether js had finished executing or not) via stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, so you may count on that.